# How to find the key in hash by a key within its nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

There is a nested hash, I need to find the first level key by the key inside of it. For instance,

```
hash = {
  a: {
    first: 0,
    second: 1
  },
  b: {
    third: 2
  }
}
```

I am given `:first` and I need to find the key it belongs to, in this case it would be  `:a` . Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible for multiple "first level key[s]" to contain the searched key? If so what should the response be? Is depth guaranteed? Is it possible for second level keys to also reference `Hash` structures to an nth level where the searched key may be present? If so should the "first level key" still be the return value?

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to interrogate the hash multiple times, for different inner keys (`:first`, `:second`, and so on) you may wish to construct the following hash before the interrogations begin.

```
hash = { a: { first: 0, second: 1 }, b: { third: 2 } } 

h = hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| v.each { |kk,_| h[kk] = k } }
  #=> {:first=>:a, :second=>:a, :third=>:b}
```

so that later you may simply do hash lookups:

```
h[:first]
  #=> :a
```

If the hash could look like this:

```
hash = { a: { first: 0, second: 1 }, b: { third: 2, first: 3 } }
```

you may wish to define `h` as follows:

```
h = hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),h|
  v.each { |kk,_| h.update(kk=>[k]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
end
  #=> {:first=>[:a, :b], :second=>[:a], :third=>[:b]}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a. `merge!`) that employs a block (here `{ |_,o,n| o+n }`) to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for explanations of the three block variables `_`, `o` and `n`. I used `_` for the variable holding the common key to tell the reader that it is not used in the block calculations. That is common practice, though you might see, for example, `_key` in place of `_`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enumerable#find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) and [`Hash#key?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F):

```
Hash[*hash.find { |_, value| value.key?(:first) }]
# {:a=>{:first=>0, :second=>1}}
```

Really, being a Hash it's possible you can have the same key in different hashes within the "main" hash, so probably `select` is an option as well.

Comment: thanks lots! this works for me. may i ask why do we use * in front of the hash? @sebastian-palma

Comment: I think the OP is looking for `:a`, i.e. `hash.find { |_, value| value.key?(:first) }.first`

Comment: That's used to "expand" the content to an array of parameters for `Hash::[]`, it'd be similar to wrap the `hash.find { ... }` as an array `Hash[[hash.find { |_, value| value.key?(:first) }]]` @unnamed_road.

Comment: road, `g = hash.find { |_, value| value.key?(:first) } #=> [:a, {:first=>0, :second=>1}]`.  If you examine the doc [Hash::\[\]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) you will see that you could write `Hash[*g] #=> {:a=>{:first=>0, :second=>1}}` or `Hash[[g]] #=> {:a=>{:first=>0, :second=>1}}`. In the first case the splat operator `*` causes `Hash[*g]` to be evaluated `Hash[:a, {:first=>0, :second}]`, which is one of the ways the (class) method `Hash::[]` can be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the [`keys`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#keys-method) and then [`find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#find-method) the one for which `hash` has a key named `:first`:

```
hash.keys.find { |k| hash[k].key?(:first) }
#=> :a
```

Use `select` instead of `find` to get an array of all matching keys (if there can be multiple).